# Using Laravel Horizon with tymondesigns/jwt-auth

Tags: laravel, jwt, horizon

I'm installing horizon (for the first time) on a Laravel 7 SPA application (vue+jwt-auth), but I'm having trouble getting it to work with the tymondesigns/jwt-auth package.

When I go to myapp.com/horizon, I get a 403 error

I did not find any documentation clearly explaining the procedure to use the jwt authentication middleware to connect to Horizon in production. Has anyone know how to tell Horizon to use jwt-auth middleware?

Comment: it's unclear what you exactly asking for. You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Horizon for the first time, I'm not using classic Laravel authentication, I'm going through jwt-auth, so when I go to myapp.com/horizon, I get a 403 error. I don't know how to tell Horizon to use jwt-auth middleware.

Comment: Hello. Have you solved this issue?